# Vue setInterval / clear interval timing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an image slider using Vue.js with a setInterval function looping through 4 images, I have it working almost to my liking except on the last image clearInterval call there is too long of a delay before the image slider starts again on the 0 image index. Is there a way to go directly back to the first index / image smoother / quicker?

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "Slider",
  data() {
    return {
      currentSliderIndex: 0
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.currentSliderIndex = this.currentSliderIndex + 1;

      if (this.currentSliderIndex > 4) {
        clearInterval();
        this.currentSliderIndex = 0;
      }
    }, 4000);
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: shouldnt you pass interval id to clear interval

Comment: See documentation for [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). Use the return value of that function as an argument of `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you need to call `clearInterval`, which isn't doing anything in this case because you aren't passing the ID of your interval (as Peter Wolf points out in the comments).

Your problem is that you are only resetting the `currentSliderIndex` if `currentSliderIndex > 4`. You need to check if `currentSliderIndex > 3`, because index 4 will be the 5th element in your array of images. Try this instead:

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "Slider",
  data() {
    return {
      currentSliderIndex: 0
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.currentSliderIndex = this.currentSliderIndex + 1;

      if (this.currentSliderIndex > 3) {
        this.currentSliderIndex = 0;
      }
    }, 4000);
  }
};
</script>
```